# How to send and receive data via CBL2CAPChannel

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, l2cap

I'm trying to open an L2CAP channel between 2 iOS devices and transfer data both ways. One of the devices acts as a central the other one as a peripheral.

**On the peripheral side:**

I publish an L2CAPChannel like this:

```
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
        peripheral.publishL2CAPChannel(withEncryption: false)
    }
}
```

Tried both true and false for encryption.

Then once the channel is published I get the PSM from the didPublishL2CAPChannel delegate method and create a service with a characteristic containing the PSM as it's value and start advertising it.

**On the central side:**

I scan for peripherals, find the right one, connect to it, start discovering services, then once the service is discovered I discover characteristics. I find the characteristic, read it's value and get the PSM. Then I do this:

```
self.peripheral.openL2CAPChannel(psm)
```

Then I get a call back in the delegate method that the channel is open and do this:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didOpen channel: CBL2CAPChannel?, error: Error?) {
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Couldn't open channel. Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    self.l2capChannel = channel
    self.l2capChannel?.inputStream.delegate = self
    self.l2capChannel?.outputStream.delegate = self
    print("L2CAP channel opened with \(peripheral.name ?? "unknown")")
}
```

This prints:

```
L2CAP channel opened with mrsta’s iPad
```

**On the peripheral side again:**

I get the call back in the delegate method:

```
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didOpen channel: CBL2CAPChannel?, error: Error?) {
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Couldn't open channel. Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    self.l2capChannel = channel
    self.l2capChannel?.inputStream.delegate = self
    self.l2capChannel?.outputStream.delegate = self
    print("L2CAP channel opened")
}
```

This prints:

```
[CoreBluetooth] No central present! Creating a new object. This shouldn't happen.
L2CAP channel opened
```

So far it seems like the channel is opened on both sides. I just wonder what's that message in the above print "... No central present!..."

After a while I start getting messages like this in the console:

```
[CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 436
[CoreBluetooth] No known channel matching peer <CBPeripheral: 0x2829de120, identifier = 241BAA6F-0BFD-9F5A-1EC9-35A4FD246DF5, name = mrsta’s iPad, state = connected> with psm 192
[CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
```

I have no idea what these mean. Any suggestions?

I've also implemented the StreamDelegate method on both sides:

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    print("Stream Event occurred: \(eventCode)")
    if eventCode == .hasSpaceAvailable {
        self.tryToWrite()
    }
}
```

But the above delegate method is never called. I try to write to the output stream like this (tryToWrite called from the didOpen channel delegate method on the central side):

```
func tryToWrite() {
    let string = "Hello"
    let stringData = Data(from: string)
    let _ = stringData.withUnsafeBytes { write(stuff: $0, to: self.l2capChannel, withMaxLength: stringData.count) }
}

func write(stuff: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, to channel: CBL2CAPChannel?, withMaxLength maxLength: Int) {
    let result = channel?.outputStream.write(stuff, maxLength: maxLength)
    print("Write result: \(String(describing: result))")
}
```

And the result is:

```
Write result: Optional(-1)
```

Which based on the documentation means that the write failed.

Please tell me what am I missing? What are those errors that I get after opening the channel and what is the right way to write and read data?

Comment: Hello. I also errors similar to yours when working with L2CAP channels. Did you find any good answer to your problem?

Comment: No, I actually gave up on this. I had a deadline to finish the project and couldn't make it work with L2CAP. I ended up using WriteDataWithoutResponse, but it works much slower than needed.

Comment: OK. Do you mean much faster then needed? Or not fast enough.

Comment: Using L2CAP channel is the fastest way to transfer data. WriteDataWithoutResponse is slower than that. That's why I wanted to make L2CAP channels work, but I couldn't. I'm trying to transfer photos between phones and WriteDataWithoutResponse is not fast enough, but still better than nothing and definitelly faster than WriteDataWithResponse.

Comment: OK, I see. We are having similar problems then. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use L2CAP and It is working. What I do in both "didOpen" functions is

```
self.l2capChannel = channel

self.l2capChannel?.inputStream.delegate = self 
self.l2capChannel?.inputStream.schedule(in: .main, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
self.l2capChannel?.inputStream.open()

self.l2capChannel?.outputStream.delegate = self
self.l2capChannel?.outputStream.schedule(in: .main, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
self.l2capChannel?.outputStream.open()
```

and when I don't need them anymore I closed them

```
self.l2capChannel?.inputStream.close()
self.l2capChannel?.inputStream.remove(from: .main, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)

self.l2capChannel?.outputStream.close()
self.l2capChannel?.outputStream.remove(from: .main, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)

self.l2capChannel? = nil
```